# Is $f(z)= z^2\bar{z}$ not differentiable anywhere?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential

**Question**: prove that $\frac{d}{dz}(z^2\bar{z})$ does not exists anywhere.

**My attempt**: my intention is that it is differentiable at origin.

Since, $$f'(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}$$

$$=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z^2\bar{z}}{z}$$

$$=0$$

Hence, I think that, it must be differentiable at origin. **question is from standard reputed textbook but is wrong Or I am incorrect somewhere?**

However, at other points it is not differentiable but I am unable to prove it.  :-(

Please help me....

Comment: I don't know, why negative votes? At least please comment the reason for negative votes.

Comment: For non-differentiability, show that the Cauchy Riemann equations aren't satisfied. It is easy to find the real and imaginary parts of $f$ if you note $z^{2}\bar{z} = z|z|^{2}$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood sir, $u_x= 3x^2 + y^2$ ,$u_y= 2xy$ and $v_x= 2xy$ and $v_y= x^2+3y^2$ , so from these Cauchy reimann equations satisfied at origin? If yes then how can we conclude $f(z)$ is not differentiable at origin? Or am I true  that, question is wrong, f(z) is differentiable at origin.

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi see this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations at      2.3 Independence of the complex conjugate

Comment: $f$ is nowhere analytic, nowhere holomorphic. Maybe someone mixed up being complex differentiable at a point and being analytic or holomorphic at a point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cauchy Riemann equation $u_{x} = v_{y}$ implies 
$$3x^{2}+y^{2} = x^{2}+3y^{2} \implies x^{2}+y^{2}=0 \implies z=0$$
so that $f$ is not differentiable if $z \ne 0$. Conversely, you correctly prove that $f$ is differentiable at $z=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $f$ is differntiable only at $z = 0$, In any other point:

$z\longmapsto z^2\bar z$ differentiable $\implies z\longmapsto\frac{z^2\bar z}{z^2} = \bar z$ differentiable

and the conjugation isn't differentiable in any point.